# Useful USB file transfer on iOS - How to hide some files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, hide, file-transfer

I am building the iPhone application, which will support the USB file transfer function.

I modified the `.plist` file. And now I can see the files in `Documents` directory of my own iPhone application, through iTunes on Mac.

Everything is okay. However, there are some important files, which shouldn't show to the users, such as the configuration file, the database file and so on.

So here is my question - **is it possible to hide some files**?

Just easily, I can keep the important files out of the `Documents` directory. But when I update the application from appstore, these will be deleted.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try prefixing the files with a `.`. thats the conventional way for unix systems or the main type of filesystem for mac or.... it works on mac so maybe it'll work on idevice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to prefix the files with a dot. And it works great.

Thank you, DanZimm.